# Template type deduction with a non-copyable class

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have an autolocker class which looks something like this:

```
template <T>
class autolocker {
public:
    autolocker(T *l) : lock(l) {
        lock->lock();
    }

    ~autolocker() {
        lock->unlock();
    }
private:
    autolocker(const autolocker&);
    autolocker& operator=(const autolocker&);
private:
    T *lock;
};
```

Obviously the goal is to be able to use this autolocker with anything that has a lock/unlock method without resorting to virtual functions.

Currently, it's simple enough to use like this:

```
autolocker<some_lock_t> lock(&my_lock); // my_lock is of type "some_lock_t"
```

but it is illegal to do:

```
autolocker lock(&my_lock); // this would be ideal
```

Is there anyway to get template type deduction to play nice with this (keep in my autolocker is non-copyable). Or is it just easiest to just specify the type?

Comment: I'm curious: Is there some reason `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is inadequate or undesirable?

Comment: @greyfade: It is for use in my toy OS's kernel. So I am starting from scratch library wise :-).

Comment: Fair enough, then. Good luck to you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use the scope-guard technique

```
struct autolocker_base {
    autolocker_base() { } 
protected:
    // ensure users can't copy-as it
    autolocker_base(autolocker_base const&) 
    { }

    autolocker_base &operator=(autolocker_base const&)
    { return *this; }
};

template <T>
class autolocker : public autolocker_base {
public:
    autolocker(T *l) : lock(l) {
        lock->lock();
    }

    autolocker(const autolocker& o)
      :autolocker_base(o), lock(o.lock)
    { o.lock = 0; }

    ~autolocker() {
        if(lock)
          lock->unlock();
    }

private:
    autolocker& operator=(const autolocker&);

private:
    mutable T *lock;
};
```

Then write a function creating the autolocker

```
template<typename T>
autolocker<T> makelocker(T *l) {
  return autolocker<T>(l);
}

typedef autolocker_base const& autolocker_t;
```

You can then write it like this:

```
autolocker_t lock = makelocker(&my_lock);
```

Once the const reference goes out of scope, the destructor is called. It doesn't need to be virtual. At least GCC [optimizes this quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name/2419715#2419715).

Sadly, this means you have to make your locker-object copyable since you need to return it from the maker function. But the old object won't try to unlock twice, because its pointer is set to 0 when it's copied, so it's safe.

Comment: +1. A similar pattern is used by `boost::weak_ptr<>` and is really effective.

Comment: Now you have to write `makelocker` instead of repeating the type. Sure, you don't have to name the type twice this way, but it's still cumbersome. I think this should be doable storing a pointer to an unlocking static member function instance. That would let you write `autolocker lock(&mutex);` and be done. See my answer for a sketch of that.

Comment: Hm, having rethought it, i think that "autolocker_base" doesn't need to be publicly copyable. Only the "autolocker<T>" needs to be. Adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can't get away with `autolocker` being a template, because you want to use it as a type, and templates must be instantiated in order to obtain types.

But type-erasure might be used to do what you want. You turn the class template into a class and its constructor into a member template. But then you'd have to dynamically allocate an inner implementation object.
Better, store a pointer to a function that performs the unlock and let that function be an instance of a template chosen by the templatized constructor. Something along these lines:

```
// Comeau compiles this, but I haven't tested it. 
class autolocker {
public:
    template< typename T >
    autolocker(T *l) : lock_(l), unlock_(&unlock<T>) { l->lock(); }

    ~autolocker()                                    { unlock_(lock_); }
private:
    autolocker(const autolocker&);
    autolocker& operator=(const autolocker&);
private:
    typedef void (*unlocker_func_)(void*);

    void *lock_;
    unlocker_func_ unlock_;

    template <typename T>
    static void unlock(void* lock)                   { ((T*)lock)->unlock(); }
};
```

I haven't actually tried this and the syntax might be wrong (I'm not sure how to take the address of a specific function template instance), but I think this should be doable in principle. Maybe someone comes along and fixes what I got wrong.

I like this a lot more than the scope guard, which, for some reason, I never really liked at all.

Comment: Wow, this is a sweet way to do it :) I like it better than my scope-guard thing too, since it avoids the copy-constructor/mutable madness :) I wonder how compilers' optimizers handle it? Would be interesting to see :)

Comment: @Johannes: Bear in mind that I haven't even compiled this. Do you think it would work? Anyway, I think compilers are often not very good at inlining functions called through pointers. But I guess this wouldn't matter all that much since calling `unlock()` on the lock will most likely dominate the run-time. Or what optimization were you thinking about?

Comment: Dang, Comeau's online compiler doesn't like it. Anyway, if taking the address of a static member function template doesn't work this way (it's Saturday night close to 2am here and I'm not going to work this out), putting it into a static member function of a local class template might do the trick.

Comment: @sbi yes i think this technique will work. I remember GCC had problems in the past of taking the address of a specific function template specialization, but to be fair the Standard in C++03 times didn't state that it would work. C++0x added rules that make this work. IIRC, these rules are implemented retroactively by current C++03 compilers i'm aware of, though (GCC, clang and comeau). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#115 . Without that rule, even if you were to cast to `unlocker_func_`, you would never yield a pointer since `T` couldn't be deduced.

Comment: @sbi, well after changing the typos it compiles fine for me on comeau :)

Comment: @Johannes: Yeah, eventually it bothered me too much and I went and massaged it until Comeau agreed with it. _But I'm not going to test this now._ I'm going to go to bed instead. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I think jwismar is correct and what you want is not possible with C++.  However, *a similar* (not direct analogue) construct is possible with C++0x, using several new features (rvalues/moving and auto variable type):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class autolocker_impl
{
public:
  autolocker_impl(T *l) : lock(l) {
    lock->lock();
  }

  autolocker_impl (autolocker_impl&& that)
    : lock (that.lock)
  {
    that.lock = 0;
  }

  ~autolocker_impl() {
    if (lock)
      lock->unlock();
  }
private:
  autolocker_impl(const autolocker_impl&);
  autolocker_impl& operator=(const autolocker_impl&);
private:
  T *lock;
};

template <typename T>
autolocker_impl <T>
autolocker (T* lock)
{
  return autolocker_impl <T> (lock);
}

struct lock_type
{
  void lock ()
  { std::cout << "locked\n"; }
  void unlock ()
  { std::cout << "unlocked\n"; }
};

int
main ()
{
  lock_type l;
  auto x = autolocker (&l);
}
```

Comment: Oh i see now my boolean flag wasn't necessary. I could just use the pointer as the "don't call unlock" flag, like you do in your code. +1 for the C++0x way.

Answer (score 0):

`autolocker` is a class template, not a class.  Your "this would be ideal" is showing something that doesn't make sense in C++.

Comment: __If there's one thing I've learned in almost twenty years of programming in C++, it's that "there's no way to do this" usually is a temporary state of affairs.__ Of course, `autolocker` as presented was a template and so it wouldn't work, but three people came up with three different techniques to circumvent that obstruction. That's a typical situation and that's why people like to run such problems by peers: Someone might twist their head just far enough to see the problem from an angle nobody had looked at it from and comes up with a way to do the undoable. `:)`