# (Ab)using constructors and destructors for side effects bad practice? Alternatives?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constructor, destructor

In OpenGL, one often writes code like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
// modify the current matrix and use it
glPopMatrix();
```

Essentially, the state is changed, then some actions are performed that use the new state, and finally the state is restored.

Now there are two problems here:

1. It's easy to forget to restore the state.
2. If the code in between throws an exception, the state is never restored.

In true object-based programming style, I have written some utility classes to overcome these problems, like so:

```
struct WithPushedMatrix {
    WithPushedMatrix() { glPushMatrix(); }
    ~WithPushedMatrix() { glPopMatrix(); }
};
```

Now I can simply write my previous example like this:

```
WithPushedMatrix p;
// modify the current matrix and use it
```

The exact moment of restoring is determined by the lifetime of `p`. If an exception is thrown, `p`'s destructor gets called, the state is restored, and life is good.

Still, I'm not entirely happy. Especially if the constructor takes some arguments (e.g. flags for `glEnable`), it's easy to forget to assign the object to a variable:

```
WithEnabledFlags(GL_BLEND); // whoops!
```

The temporary gets destroyed immediately, and the state change is reversed prematurely.

Another issue is that anyone else reading my code might get confused: "Why is there a variable declared here that is never used? Let's get rid of it!"

So, my questions: Is this a good pattern? Does it maybe even have a name? Are there any problems with this approach that I'm overlooking? Last but not least: are there any good alternatives?

*Update*: Yes, I guess it's a form of RAII. But not in the way RAII is normally used, because it involves a seemingly useless variable; the "resource" in question is never accessed explicitly. I just didn't realize that this particular usage was so common.

Comment: So you have a silver "c++ tag" badge and never heard of RAII?

Comment: @mxp: That's a very, erm, _interesting_ observation you made there.

Comment: Although i don't encourage it (names are good), you can get templates to get rid of names entirely. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name/2419715#2419715) is an example implementation (final version at the very bottom), which GCC entirely optimizes.

Comment: @mxp: Yes, I have. It wouldn't call this RAII because, strictly speaking, no resource is acquired. Then again, RAII is a misnomer anyway.

Comment: Well, formally speaking - yes, there's no obvious entity acquired. But consider the following: the computer operates by changing states. When for example you create a bitmap (and bind it to a wrapper class instance) you cause state change. The same goes here - you "push the matrix" (no idea what exactly happens) and this changes state. That's why creating a bitmap and "pushing a matrix" are related to resource management in the same way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I like the idea of using RAII to control OpenGL state, but I'd actually take it one step further: have your `WithFoo` class constructor take a function pointer as a parameter, which contains the code you want to execute in that context. Then *don't* create named variables, and just work with temporaries, passing in the action you want to execute in that context as a lambda. (needs C++0x, of course - can work with regular function pointers too but it's not nearly as pretty.)
Something like this: *(edited to restore exception-safety)*

```
class WithPushedMatrix
{
public:
    WithPushedMatrix()
    {
        glPushMatrix();
    }

    ~WithPushedMatrix()
    {
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    template <typename Func>
    void Execute(Func action)
    {
        action();
    }
};
```

And use it like so:

```
WithPushedMatrix().Execute([]
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //etc. etc.
});
```

The temporary object will set up your state, execute the action and then tear it down automatically; you don't have "loose" state variables floating around, and the actions executing under the context become strongly associated with it. You can even nest multiple contextual actions without worrying about destructor order.

You can even take this further and make a generic `WithContext` class that takes additional setup and teardown function parameters.

*edit*: Had to move the `action()` call into a separate `Execute` function to restore exception-safety - if it's called in the constructor and throws, the destructor won't get called.

#### edit2: Generic technique -

So I fiddled around with this idea some more, and came up with something better:
I'll define a `With` class, that creates the context variable and stuffs it into a `std::auto_ptr` in it's initializer, then calls the `action`:

```
template <typename T>
class With
{
public:
    template <typename Func>
    With(Func action) : context(new T()) 
    { action(); }

    template <typename Func, typename Arg>
    With(Arg arg, Func action) : context(new T(arg))
    { action(); }

private:
    const std::auto_ptr<T> context;
};
```

Now you can combine it with context type that you defined originally:

```
struct PushedMatrix 
{
    PushedMatrix() { glPushMatrix(); }
    ~PushedMatrix() { glPopMatrix(); }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
With<PushedMatrix>([]
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //etc. etc.
});
```

or

```
With<EnabledFlag>(GL_BLEND, []
{
    //...
});
```

Benefits:

1. Exception-safety is handled by the `auto_ptr` now, so if `action` throws, the context will still get destroyed properly.
2. No more need for an `Execute` method, so it looks clean again! :)
3. Your "context" classes are dead-simple; all of the logic is handled by the `With` class so you just need to define a simple ctor/dtor for each new type of context.

One niggle: As I've written it above, you need to declare manual overloads for the ctor for as many parameters as you need; although even just one should cover most OpenGL use cases, this isn't really nice.
This should be neatly fixed with variadic templates - just replace `typename Arg` in the ctor with `typename ...Args` - but it'll depend on compiler support for that (MSVC2010 doesn't have them yet).

Comment: +1 too, it's semantically better since the code inside "withPushedMatrix" is really "withPushedMatrix", it doesn't look like a hack ; I think I'll use this for my own OpenGL apps :p

Comment: @Alexandre: Thanks! I haven't started using C++0x features enough myself yet, but having been using C# a lot lately, this just seemed like a really natural way to do things.

Comment: Wait, there is a problem: if an exception happens inside the lambda, the destructor of ~WithPushedMatrix won't be called ; a simple function with a try-catch around "action()" would be better in fact

Comment: Beware, exception safety impose we do `WithPushedMatrix(Func action) { GlPushMatrix(); try { action(); } catch (...) { glPopMatrix(); throw; } }`, since if the constructor throws, the destructor doesn't get called. But you have to duplicate the call to glPopMatrix(), this makes it less beautiful.

Comment: @Tomaka, Alexandre: Exception-safety restored! Slightly uglier, but no need for an explicit try-catch this way.

Comment: @tzaman: A nicer way to deal with exceptions in the user's action would be to put the calls to `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` into the ctor and dtor of a base class and the action into the derived class' ctor. Fully constructed sub-objects will have their dtors called when exceptions occur in a constructor, and by the time `action()` throws in the derived class, the base class has already been fully constructed.

Comment: -1: How do I return from the enclosing function when I'm *in a lambda block*?  This solution impedes the control flow, I can't break out of the block. Not so good.

Comment: @Luther: The same way you return from any enclosing function.

Comment: I think @Luther's point is good. You won't be able to break, return, continue etc anymore from within the lambda block affecting any code in its enclosing function.

Comment: I think it's a clever answer (I did something like this once and immediate realized it was a bad idea), so +1 to that, but -1 because it really isn't a good way to go about things.

Comment: @sbi - nice tip about the derived class! That's probably the cleanest way to do this. 
@GMan - bad idea because of the control issues @Luther mentions (which are admittedly a problem), or some other reason?

Comment: Tough choice, so many good answers... thank you all! I'm accepting this one because it actually addresses the problems with the approach, and suggests the cleanest (albeit somewhat less powerful) solution.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks! I've updated it with an (imo) even better approach, take a look. :)

Answer (score 22):

Using objects like that is called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and is very typical for resource management. Yes, sometimes you'll have temporary objects destroyed too early because you forgot to provide a varible name. But you have one big advantage here - code becomes more exception safe and cleaner - you don't have to call all the cleanup stuff manually on all possible code paths.

One advice: use reasonable variable names, not `p`. Call it `matrixSwitcher` or something like that, so that readers don't think it's a useless variable.

Comment: sharptooth, I went in and added a link to RAII. I hop you don't mind.

Comment: If you want to boost the google rank of an answer on stackoverflow then you should link to that answer rather than wikipedia. ;)

Comment: How is this getting +21 upvotes in 4 hours? The answer identifies the RAII pattern like **almost all the other answers too** and apart from that **repeats what the OP already knows**. It ends with a vague advice to name the variables in meaningful way. It is a mediocre answer at best and if this means 200 reputation, then the SO reputation system is seriously broken. I have seen clever, thoughtful and sophisticated answers on SO which end up with +3 or less and this is getting +21?

Comment: There is something to be said for brevity.

Comment: +1 for recommenting a reasonable variable name. I dislike omitting names, which is somhow "lazy", i think :)

Comment: @Luther: If the rep system and the way it works (or doesn't, depending on your POV) works you up so much, why do you waste your time here? You have lost in this round (me, too, BTW). So what? SO cannot guarantee that the "best" answer gets up-voted the most - even if there were an universally agreed way to determine "best". Still, in general SO is a lot better than many other forums I have been at. So just relax, post answers if you feel like you know them and find the time to do so, rejoice when you get up-voted to the top, and try to learn something (about the topic or SO) when you don't.

Comment: -1 This is different from RAII... there's no "resource" conceptually getting "acquired". It's a modification of an existing resource followed by un-doing that action, not acquisition and subsequent release of a new resource. (The difference being that this has a side-effect on users that don't actually use the variable, whereas RAII conceptually doesn't.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I cannot agree. Does allocating memory count as acquiring a resource? I guess it does. Well, that's just changing the heap state. Almost everything that a program does is changing the state.

Comment: @sharptooth: I think you're thinking too hard. Think of it in terms of functional programming. What I'm trying to say is that acquiring memory is **conceptually** a side-effect-free operation; i.e., a sane program does not (and should not) depend on the change in the heap state for correctness. The fact that the heap state changes is an irrelevant implementation detail that is not (nor should be) of concern to the caller. Compare that with the OpenGL scenario, where the state change is very relevant and absolutely crucial for the caller to be aware of. They're fundamentally very different.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Come on, you had no memory allocated before allocation and now you've got some memory because of allocation and can use that memory. That's a state change too and it's of the same kind as OpenGL manipulation. If you fail to allocate memory your program goes nuts.

Comment: @sharptooth: *You* "come on"! Just because there's a bit getting changed somewhere that doesn't mean it's relevant to the program. Read this **carefully**: when you allocate memory, you've acquired a **new** resource to work with. You have ***not*** made any modifications to **existing** resources that your program depends on for correctness. This is **fundamentally *the opposite*** of the OpenGL manipulation, whose *entire point* is to manipulate resources **already in use** rather than to allocate new ones. I hope this makes sense now because I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Okay, I believe this attempt to classify stuff only limits the toolset. With something new created or without using constructors and destructors and stack unwinding for consistently changing the program state is very useful and very reliable.

Comment: FWIW, I think there's some validity to the perspective that the "resource" here is a *context* in which certain work can be done... it's not a point worthy of great debate.  Separately, "scope guard" is another related term (e.g. Alexandrescu's generalised solution from ~ a decade ago).  And I'd be more concerned about having the type name convey the utility (e.g. ending with `Guard`), rather than hoping the client code will create a meaningful variable name....

Comment: @TonyD: Great comment, exactly summed up my thoughts.

Comment: @sharptooth: It's "reliable" in the sense that it will cause the thread to clean up after itself, sure. But it's *unreliable* in the sense that you can't rely on your code behaving the way you would expect with regular RAII, because non-users of the code are affected; e.g. the render target changes even though all the visible objects have stayed the same. This leakage contaminates the entire program state and makes it harder to reason about, and the OP was correct to call it "abuse" -- it's only done this way because there are no better facilities in C++, not because it's proper use of RAII.

Comment: @Mehrdad: that's the fault of `glPushMatrix` being modeled as an operation on global state, rather than the approach sharptooth's suggested here (otherwise it'd be nice to pass the OpenGL variables/state being affected as a constructor argument to the guard).  Separately, sbi's answer provides a nice compromise where the scope guard variable's visible at the later points of usage.

Comment: @TonyD: Well I didn't downvote because OpenGL was designed poorly or because the solution was poor; I downvoted because this is *not* "RAII" and and is *not* "very typical" for "resource management", precisely because this isn't really resource management. That part of the answer is just plain wrong. If it had said something more reasonable like "*scope guard*" it'd have been much better than RAII.

Answer (score 6):

As was pointed out by others, this is a well-known and encouraged pattern in C++.

A way to deal with the problem of forgetting the variable name is to define operations so that they need the variable. Either by making the possible actions a member of the RAII class:

```
PushedMatrix pushed_matrix;;
pushed_matrix.transform( /*...*/ );
```

or by making functions take the RAII class as an argument:

```
PushedMatrix pushed_matrix;
transform_matrix( pushed_matrix, /*...*/ );
```

Answer (score 5):

**I'd like to point out, that my answer actually contains useful information (more that a vague reference to RAII which is apparently 19 upvotes worth). It does not need c++0x to work, is not hypothetical at all and fixes the OP's problems which relate to the need to declare a variable.**

---

There's a very nice way to beef up RAII constructs (or more precisly: ScopeGuards) syntactically: the if() statement accepts declarations which are *scoped to the if-block*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Lock
{
    public:
    Lock() { printf("locking\n"); }
    ~Lock() { printf("unlocking\n"); }
    operator bool () const { return true;}
};
int main()
{
    // id__ is valid in the if-block only
    if (Lock id_=Lock()) {  
        printf("..action\n");
    }
}
```

this prints:

```
locking
..action
unlocking
```

If we add a bit of syntactic sugar, we can write

```
#define WITH(X) if (X with_id_=X())
int main()
{
    WITH(Lock) {    
        printf("..action\n");
        WITH(Lock) {
            printf("more action\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And now we use the fact that *temporaries which are used to initialize a const reference remain alive as long as the const reference stays in scope*, to make it work with parameters (We also fix the nuisance that WITH(X) accepts a trailing else):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   class ScopeGuard 
   {
    public:
    mutable int dummy;
    operator bool () const { return false;}
    ScopeGuard(){}
    private:
    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard &); 
    }; 
    class Lock : public ScopeGuard
    {
        const char *s;
        public: 
        Lock(const char *s_) : s(s_) { printf("locking %s\n",s); }
        ~Lock() { printf("unlocking %s\n",s); }
    };

    #define WITH(X) if (const ScopeGuard& with_id_=X)  {} else 
    int main()
    {
        WITH(Lock("door")) {    
            printf("..action\n");
            WITH(Lock("gate")) {
                printf("more action\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

**TATA!**

A nice side effect of this method is, that all "protected" regions are uniformly identified through the `WITH(...) {...}` pattern - a nice property for code-reviews et.al.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name/2419715#2419715 which is similar to this :) Notice that your implementation of ScopeGuard is broken, because it relies on copy-elimination of the temporary (in C++03, the compiler is allowed to copy the temporary, even for binding to a const reference). If the copy is not eliminated, the destructor will be executed twice.

Comment: I don't think that needing a Variable is a real problem, but still +1 for your solution.

Comment: You may get further upvotes by getting rid of using the reserved name `__id__`. Some people are quite pedantic about their (limited amount of) upvotes. `_id_` will not conflict with implementations.

Comment: I think `if (Lock __id__=Lock()) {` should be `if (const Lock& _id_=Lock()) {` instead. Not every lock-like object can be copied.

Comment: Thank for the comments. I fixed __id__. I am not sure about the copy elimination thing: Even if copies can be eliminated, the compiler still has to respect the access level of the copy constructor. I made it private now, but none of my compilers seems to use it. Can your point me to the standard's paragraph which explains when these copies take place?

Comment: @Luther yep now it will complain about the private copy constructor. See 8.5.3/5b2.1.2 . I'm sorry to say this, but your code still uses reserved names.

Comment: To be more specific, any name with a double underscore is reserved.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about `ScopeGuard` - I'd seen this approach described before, but it didn't immediately come to mind. Should work very well.

Comment: @Johannes: It says that it is implementation defined if a copy is actually made or not, but also: "The constructor that would be used to make the copy shall be callable whether or not the copy is actually done.". What does that mean? Bug report?

Comment: It means, basically, that if the copy constructor might be called, you have to assume it will be called.  Without that clause, `Class Function() { return Class(); }` could be ill formed in a debug build, but well formed in release with optimizations enabled.

Comment: But this also means, that if a copy-ctor is not callable in a context, then the compiler should raise an error no matter if the copy-ctor is used or optimized out. This does not happen with GCC here (ScopeGuard's copy ctor is private). If Johannes' argument holds, then this means there's a defect in GCC, doesn't it?

Comment: @Luther: I would take Johannes' analysis over GCC's results anytime without even thinking. `:)`

Comment: This approach has the problem of calling code being able to use an `else {}` construct after the `WITH(x) {}` construct. I propose using a `for() {}` construct instead. It also has the benefit of not requiring a bool conversion operator `#define WITH(type) for (type const & WITH_##type##_instance = type(), * WITH_##type##_ptr = &WITH_##type##_instance; WITH_##type##_ptr != 0; WITH_##type##_ptr = 0)`

Comment: And any decent optimizer should optimize away the pointer and unroll the loop.

Answer (score 4):

*Warning: C++0x-oriented answer*

The pattern you're using is RAII and it's widely used for resource management. The only possible alternative is to use try-catch blocks, but it usually makes your code a bit too messy.

Now the problems.
First if you don't want to code a different class for each combinaison of OpenGL functions, there is another benefit of C++0x which is that you can write lambda functions and store them in a variable. So if I was you, I would create a class like this:

```
template<typename Destr>
class MyCustom {
public:
    template<typename T>
    MyCustom(T onBuild, Destr onDestroy) : 
        _onDestroy(std::move(onDestroy))
    {
        onBuild();
    }

    ~MyCustom() { _onDestroy(); }

private:
    Destr    _onDestroy;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
MyCustom<T2> buildCustom(T1 build, T2 destruct)   { return MyCustom<T2>(std::move(build), std::move(destruct)); }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
auto matrixPushed = buildCustom([]() { glPushMatrix(); }, []() { glPopMatrix(); });
```

Or even better here:

```
auto matrixPushed = buildCustom(&glPushMatrix, &glPopMatrix);
```

This would also solve the problem of "why is this useless variable here", since its purpose now becomes obvious.

The function passed to the constructor should be inlined, so there is no performance overhead. The destructor should be stored like a function pointer, since lambda functions with nothing inside the brackets [] should be implemented like plain functions (according to the standards).

Your "variable instantly destroyed" problem would also be partially solved using "buildCustom" since you can see more easily where you forgot the variable.

Answer (score 3):

To help you understand how long c++ programmers have been doing this, I learned about this technique in the late 90's working with COM.

I think it's a personal choice as to the exact mechanism you use to leverage the fundamental properties of c++ stack frames and destructors to make your object lifetime management easier.  I wouldn't go very far out of my way to avoid needing to assign to a variable.

(this next thing I'm not 100% sure about but I'm putting it in hopes that someone will chime in - I know I've done this in the past but I couldn't find it in Google just now and I've been trying to remember... see, garbage collectors have dulled my mind!)

I believe you can force the scope with a plain old pair of curlys (POPOC).

```
{ // new stack frame
  auto_ptr<C> instanceA(new C);
  {
     auto_ptr<C> instanceB(new C);
  }
  // instanceB is gone
} 
// instanceA is gone
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typical RAII example. Disadvantage of this method is appearing of many additional classes.
To solve this problem you may create generic "guard" class if it is possible.
There are another alternative: boost "Scope Exit" library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html). You may try it, if you can depend on boost of course.

Answer (score 1):

[ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758;jsessionid=GSR5Q53UQXFLBQE1GHRSKHWATMY32JVN) comes to mind. Please note that with C++0x bind and variadic templates it may be rewritten to be much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before, but I must admit, it is somewhat cool.
But I wouldn't use it, as it is not really intuitive.

EDIT: As sharptooth pointed out, this is called RAII. The example I found on wikipedia wraps also the operations on the resource in method calls. In your example, this would look like the following:

```
WithPushedMatrix p;
p.setFLag(GL_BLEND);
p.doSomething();
```

Then it is clear for what the variable is, and other developers will get the intuition if they read your code. Of course, the OpenGL code is then hidden, but I think one gets used to it really fast.

Comment: typical when dealing with locks, opening/closing files, memory allocation, etc. It's called RAII.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is great and Idiomatic C++. The downside is that you basically write a (custom) Wrapper around the C OpenGL library. It would be great if such a Library existed, maybe something like an (semi-)official OpenGL++ lib. 
That said, I have written code like this (from Memory), and have been very happy with it:

```
{
  Lighting light = Light(Color(128,128,128));
    light.pos(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  Texture tex1 = Texture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    tex1.set(Image("CoolTex.png"));

  drawObject();
}
```

The overhead in writing the wrappers in not very onerous, and the resulting code is as good as the handwritten code. And is IMHO much easier to read than the corresponding OpenGL code, even if you do not know the wrappers by heart.