# C++11 scope exit guard, a good idea?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've written a small utility class for C++11 which I use as a scope guard for easier handling of exception safety and similar things.

Seems somewhat like a hack. But I'm suprised I haven't seen it somewhere else using C++11 features. I think boost has something similar for C++98.

But is it a good idea? Or are there potential problems I have missed? Is there already a similar solution (with C++11 features) in boost or similar?

```
    namespace detail 
    {
        template<typename T>
        class scope_exit : boost::noncopyable
        {
        public:         
            explicit scope_exit(T&& exitScope) : exitScope_(std::forward<T>(exitScope)){}
            ~scope_exit(){try{exitScope_();}catch(...){}}
        private:
            T exitScope_;
        };          

        template <typename T>
        scope_exit<T> create_scope_exit(T&& exitScope)
        {
            return scope_exit<T>(std::forward<T>(exitScope));
        }
    }


#define _UTILITY_EXIT_SCOPE_LINENAME_CAT(name, line) name##line
#define _UTILITY_EXIT_SCOPE_LINENAME(name, line) _UTILITY_EXIT_SCOPE_LINENAME_CAT(name, line)
#define UTILITY_SCOPE_EXIT(f) const auto& _UTILITY_EXIT_SCOPE_LINENAME(EXIT, __LINE__) = ::detail::create_scope_exit(f)
```

and it's used something like.

```
int main () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  UTILITY_SCOPE_EXIT([&]{myfile.close();}); // Make sure to close file even in case of exception
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n"; // Imagine this could throw
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: see http://pizer.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/scope-guards-revisited-c0x-style/

Comment: You may want to have a look at my lazy-RAII classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name/2419715#2419715 . Note that your `scope_exit` relies on copy constructor elimination. If you compile this snippet without that optimization, you call the scope-exit lambda twice. See my RAII classes on how to work-around that problem.

Comment: I think myfile will be closed when it goes out of scope.  It should already be exception safe.

Comment: Here is a simple C++11 scope guard implementation that doesn't depend on copy constructor elimination and doesn't risk dangling pointers to temporaries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545195/558823

Comment: Another potential problem is your use of reserved names for your macros...

Comment: `std::experimental::scope_exit`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> But is it a good idea?

Sure. A related topic is the [RAII paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

> Or are there
>   potential problems I have missed?

You don't handle exceptions.

> Is
>   there already a similar solution (with
>   C++0x features) in boost or similar?

Alexandrescu came up with [ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758) a long time back. Both Boost and `std::tr1` has a thing called [`scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) and [`shared_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx) (with a custom deleter) that allows you to accomplish just this.

Comment: Where do I not handle exceptions? EDIT: Ofc the destructor.

Comment: Btw, scoped_ptr wasn't added to tr1 I believe?

Comment: Updated. I had missed `shared_ptr` stuff.

Comment: it wasn't Alexandrescu, it was Petru Marginean. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758

Answer (score 20):

For the record, there is [Boost ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 9):

Scope guards are definitely a good idea.  I think the scope guard concept is potent tool for exception safety.  If you can make a safer, cleaner version that Boost's [ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) using C++0x syntax, I think it would be well worth your time.

Similar to Alexandrescu's [ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758) and Boost's ScopeExit , the [D programming language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) has direct syntax for this sort of thing.  The D programming team thought the scope guard was a good enough idea that they added it [directly to the language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/statement.html#ScopeGuardStatement) (ie it's not implemented in a library).

Example.

```
void foo( bool fail )
{
   scope(exit)
   {
      writeln("I'm always printed");
   }

   scope(success) writeln("The function exited normally");

   scope(error)
      writeln("The function exited with an exception.");

   if( fail )
      throw new Exception("Die Die Die!");
}
```

The scope based guards aren't anything new.  It's functionality can easily be replicated with a class destructor (RAII and all that).  It's also possible to replace with `try/finally` in C# or Java.  Heck, even pthreads provides a rudimentary scope guard, called [pthread_cleanup_push](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cleanup_push).

What makes scope guards so powerful is when you have multiple `scope(*)` statements in the function.  It scales incredibly well, as opposed to `try/finally` which require super human powers to manage anything more than two.

Answer (score 5):

If replace create_scope_exit by a binary operator, we can remove parentheses:

```
class at_scope_exit
{
    template<typename F>
    struct scope_exit_fn_holder : boost::noncopyable
    {
        scope_exit_fn_holder(F&& f) : f(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

        F f;
        ~scope_exit_fn_holder() { f(); }
    };

    template<typename F>
    friend scope_exit_fn_holder<F> operator==(at_scope_exit, F&& f)
    {
        return scope_exit_fn_holder<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
auto atScopeExit = at_scope_exit() == [&]
{
    ...
};
```

**upd:**
Corresponding macro:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

#define AT_SCOPE_EXIT auto BOOST_PP_CAT(scopeExit_, __LINE__) = at_scope_exit() == [&]
#define AT_SCOPE_EXIT_EX(...) auto BOOST_PP_CAT(scopeExit_, __LINE__) = at_scope_exit() == [__VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: The problem with this version is that you have to come up with a unique name for each "at_scope_exit".

Comment: @ronag do you mean "for each atScopeExit"? You can use a macro with __LINE__ like in your code.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, there is [`scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) in the TS 3

Answer (score 2):

Currently using this solution:

```
struct _tag_defer {
    std::function<void()> fn;
    _tag_defer() = default;
    ~_tag_defer() { fn(); }
    void operator<<(std::function<void()> f) { fn = f; }
};
// clang-format off
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_INNER(a, b)
#define CONCAT_INNER(a, b) a ## b
#define defer_name CONCAT(__defer, __LINE__)
#define defer _tag_defer defer_name; defer_name << [&]
// clang-format on
```

Use it like:

```
{
    defer { last_code_to_execute_on_scope_exit(); };
    ...
    defer { first_code_to_execute_on_scope_exit(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation could be very much simplified using `tr1::function` and `tr1::unique_ptr`, as below:

```
namespace detail
{
    class ScopeGuard
    {
    public:
        explicit ScopeGuard(std::function<void()> onExitScope) 
            : onExitScope_(onExitScope), dismissed_(false)
        { }

        ~ScopeGuard()
        {
            try
            {
                if(!dismissed_)
                {
                    onExitScope_();
                }
            }
            catch(...){}
        }

        void Dismiss()
        {
            dismissed_ = true;
        }
    private:
        std::function<void()> onExitScope_;
        bool dismissed_;

        // noncopyable
    private:
        ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard const&);
        ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard const&);
    };
}

inline std::unique_ptr<detail::ScopeGuard> CreateScopeGuard(std::function<void()> onExitScope)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<detail::ScopeGuard>(new detail::ScopeGuard(onExitScope));
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a simplification? It also suffers from the problem that the user needs to come up with a unique name for each instance (which is the entire purpose of the macros in the implementation provide in the question).

Comment: And what is the purpose of using std::unique_ptr here? Seems to me that you could just as well do without.

Comment: Maybe you were misunderstand pongba, the ScopeGuard is useful with the std::function(in that time, it was tr1::function). If you could read Chinese you can read the post(http://mindhacks.cn/2012/08/27/modern-cpp-practices/), or translate it with google.

Answer (score 0):

my $0.02

```
struct at_scope_end
{
    std::function < void () > Action;

    at_scope_end (std::function < void () > Action) :
        Action (Action)
    {
    }

    ~at_scope_end ()
    {
        Action ();
    }
};

#define AT_SCOPE_END_CAT(x,y)    x##y
#define AT_SCOPE_END_ID(index)   AT_SCOPE_END_CAT(__sg, index)
#define AT_SCOPE_END(expr)      at_scope_end AT_SCOPE_END_ID(__LINE__) ( [&] () { expr; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

We could omit the ugly [&] stuff by putting it in the define:

```
#define UTILITY_SCOPE_EXIT(f) const auto& _UTILITY_EXIT_SCOPE_LINENAME(EXIT, __LINE__) = ::detail::create_scope_exit([&]f)
```

Then:

```
UTILITY_SCOPE_EXIT({myfile.close();});
```

Tested with MSVC++ 11.0 (VS2012). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea, but there are a couple of problems with you class.

1. you should disable the new operator (you don't want to need the user to use it in such a way that forces to call delete on this, right?)
2. you need a "commit" function, in order for this to be a [scope guard](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758?pgno=2) instead of a simple RAII

notice that if you implement point 2 you need a meaningful name for each scopeguard you instantiate. This is, in general, not a problem, but it could be in your application (or to your taste).

Finally, this question would probably have been more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Using Boost:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

template<class Fn>
class ScopeGuardDetails {
    const Fn m_fn;
public:
    constexpr ScopeGuardDetails(Fn &&fn) : m_fn(fn) {}
    ~ScopeGuardDetails() { m_fn(); }
};
#define ScopeGuardName BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(__scope_guard, _), BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_CAT(__LINE__, _), __COUNTER__))
#define defer(stmt) const auto ScopeGuardName = [](const auto _fn) { \
    return ScopeGuardDetails<decltype(_fn)> { std::move(_fn) }; \
}([&] { stmt });
```

Usage:

```
if (gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &startupInput, nullptr) == Gdiplus::Ok) {
    defer({
        gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token);
    });
    ...
}
```