# Write class to represent multi-dimensional arrays using [x,y] syntax?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to write a class/overloaded operator so that I could manipulate multidimensional arrays (on the client side) using traditional array[x,y] syntax?

Comment: The "traditional" syntax is actually using parentheses e.g. `(x, y)`. That's the syntax MATLAB, FORTRAN, etc. use to index into matrices (which are basically multidimensional arrays). Both of those languages are older than C++.

Comment: Could [overload the comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5602112/1084416) to produce some meaningful object from `x` and `y`. But this is inadvisable (see link).

Comment: @Insilico an array is accessed via square brackets, i.e. x[0] in C++, is it not?

Comment: @user997112: Yes. So? That doesn't change the fact that the syntax for addressing matrices has "traditionally" been via parentheses. It's also how virtually any C++ matrix manipulation library works as well.

Comment: a[x,y] is not the traditional C/C++ syntax for multidimensional arrays. The traditional syntax is a[x][y], and it is possible to write a class that uses this syntax. It is also possible to use a less traditional a(x,y) syntax.

Comment: You wouldn't think that this is would be a frequently asked question! But it is. And [here's the answer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html).

Comment: @Ben, if you put that in an answer I'll vote to that.