# c++ member function polymorphism issue

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm experiencing troubles with c++ inherrited member function, look at the following code:

```
binIO_t wtest(path, mode);
const void* Buff = "abcd";
wtest << Buff, 1; //no operator found
wtest.virtIO_t::operator<<(Buff), 1; //works fine
```

Exact compiler error is:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   ...

I'm surly missing some subtle decleration yet I fail to find it.

my superclass.h is:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class virtIO_t{
private:
    virtIO_t();

public:
    virtIO_t(string filePath, string fileMode);
    ~virtIO_t();

    virtual virtIO_t& operator >> (void* Buf);
    virtual virtIO_t& operator << (const void* Buf);

    virtual virtIO_t& operator << (const char val) = 0;
    virtual virtIO_t& operator >> (char &val) = 0;
};
```

and the superclass.cpp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "virtIO_t.h"

virtIO_t::virtIO_t()
{
}

virtIO_t::~virtIO_t()
{
    ...
}

virtIO_t::virtIO_t(string filePath, string fileMode){
...
}


virtIO_t& virtIO_t::operator << (const void* Buff){
    ...
}
virtIO_t& virtIO_t::operator >> (void* Buff){
    ...
}
```

and the sub.h is:

```
#pragma once
#include "virtIO_t.h"

class binIO_t : public virtIO_t{

public:
    binIO_t(string filePath, string mode);

    virtIO_t& operator << (const char val);
    virtIO_t& operator >> (char &val);
```

and the sub.cpp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "binIO_t.h"

binIO_t::binIO_t(string filePath, string mode) : virtIO_t(filePath, (string(mode) + "b").c_str()){}

    virtIO_t& binIO_t::operator << (const char val){
    ...
    }

    virtIO_t& binIO_t::operator >> (char &val){
    ...
    }
```

Comment: What do you think those commas are doing?  Probably not what you expect.

Comment: @dwcanillas which commas are you referring to?

Comment: Nevermind the comma ... first, consider exactly what C++ is saying.  *Is there* a version of `<<` which will accept a "pointer to `void`" as an acceptable input on its right-hand-side?  Apparently there isn't.  You're not coding what you think you're coding, and/or what you intend to be coding. Step back, take a deep breath, and look again.

Comment: @dwcanillas the operator<< is working fine when I call it explicitly, my question is why can't I use it implicitly?

Comment: @MikeRobinson what about the 'virtual virtIO_t& operator << (const void* Buf);' decleration? isn't it suffice?

Comment: Because the one being called implicitly is not the one being called explicitly.

Comment: @dwcanillas it's my fault that I havn't uploaded the entire class as you can read in the comments bellow, sorry for any incalrities and thank you for your effort.

Comment: @GalB1t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator

Comment: @dwcanillas  I accept that, yet it's an assignment of my c++ course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binIO_t` declares it's own `operator<<` which hides `operator<<(void*)` from base class. Try `using virtIO_t::operator<<` directive or explicitly define `operator<<(void*)` in `biunIO_t`.

Also: `, 1` does nothing.