# In c, can a switch statement have 2 arguments?

Tags: c, syntax, switch-statement, comma-operator

```
int main()
{
   switch(1,2)
   {
      case 1:printf("1");break;
      case 2:printf("2");break;
      default: printf("error");break;
   }
}
```

Is this valid in c?

I thought it shouldn't be , but when I compiled it , it shows no error and produces output 2.

Comment: There is a way to make the case statement do two cases if that's what you are asking - just not with a comma.

Comment: @jerry-jeremiah what is that way ,can you please elaborate?

Comment: An occasionally-useful trick is to do something like `switch(PAIR(x, y)) { case PAIR(1, 1): thing1; break; case PAIR(2, 1): thing2; break; case PAIR(1, 2): thing3; break; case PAIR(1, 3): thing4; break; }`, where `PAIR(a, b)` is a macro that expands to something like `10 * a + b`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is *valid*, because in this case, the `,` is a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.17, *Comma operator*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. **Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.**

This (evaluates and) discards the left operand and uses the value of the right (*side*) one. So, the above statement is basically the same as

```
switch(2)
```

Just to elaborate, it ***does not** use two values*, as you may have expected something like, switching on *either 1 or 2*.

Comment: Can this comma operator be useful in any case?

I am just asking this 'cause I don't think it is useful in this case.

Comment: @DhruvaMehrotra Well, that is a broad question. It's yes and no, you never know.There's technically no issue, that's all.

Comment: @DhruvaMehrotra you can see some cases where it's useful in the duplicate question. Out of those it's rarely useful in C. In C++ you can overload it so many people find a few more useful cases for it http://stackoverflow.com/a/5602236/995714

Comment: The comma operator is usefull, when you define macros