# How to combine operator << with the comma operator to assign multiple values to an array or vector class member?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to overload operator `<<` combined with the comma operator in order to provide a way of assigning multiple comma-separated values to a `std::array` or `std::vector` class member.

For example, given the following class declaration:

```
class MyClass{
public:
   MyClass() {}
   ~MyClass() {} 
private:
   std::array<double, 5> a_{};
}
```

I would like to be able to use the following syntax:

```
MyClass m;
m << 9, 10, 11, 99, 5;
```

Which in turn would update `a_` by setting the corresponding values (9 at a_[0], 10 at a_[1] and so on). Operator `<<` should also raise an error if the number of comma-separated values does not match `std::array::size`

Thanks for any advice on how to proceed!

Comment: Might I suggest just overloading `<<` and using initializer lists instead? Then it would look like `m << {1, 2, 3}` instead. The logic should be much simpler.

Comment: Have you considered using [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) instead? `MyClass m{9, 10, 11, 99, 5};` would be more recognizable to more programmers.

Comment: You could take a look at [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: First of all you need to implement an overloaded `operator<<` for your class. Then you need to make it return some object which have an overloaded `operator,` function which in turn returns itself (or another instance of the same class which overloads the comma operator). But that's a lot of work instead of implementing a constructor to handle it properly (either though a variable number of arguments somehow, or better yet through an `std::initializer_list`).

Comment: Overloading `,` operator might look [suspicious](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5602136).

Comment: @user4581301 Yes sorry about that I corrected it

Comment: Gordie Howe, Guy Lafleur, Mark Messier, Wayne Gretzky, and Guy Lapointe. Those are some good numbers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The idea is to provide a convenient syntax. I want to mimic what Eigen does for initializing Matrices: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks though for putting me on the right track!

Comment: @Claudiu Yes that would also be a good option.