# Making an Operator Overload context specific

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comma-operator

I am learning about C++ in my spare time, and I am implementing a class that overloads the subscript / `[]` operators. Now, I wanted to be able to pass two or more arguments to the subscript operators as follows (separated by a comma):

`myObject[i,j,...]`, where the arguments could for instance be `string`s or `int`s

I found out that C++ does not allow the subscript operator to accept more than one argument. However, I read about overloading the comma operator in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator/18136340#18136340), as an alternative solution to that 'problem'.

In the example, the comma operator is overloaded using very specific signature, with two custom `Enum`'s, but I can see that it's not a good idea to overload the comma operator for general type pairs (which would be my use case).

With my limited knowledge of C++, that made me curious about whether it would be at all possible to limit the 'scope' or use of the comma operator overload to a specific situation or context, e.g, only in the subscript operator overload definition, giving me the functionality I am interested in, without causing interference elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict regular function/operator to context, but you can restrict it by scope thanks to namespace.

```
enum class E {A, B};

struct C
{
    int operator [](const std::pair<E, E>& p) const
    {
        return data[static_cast<int>(p.first) * 2 + static_cast<int>(p.second)];
    }
    std::array<int, 4> data{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
};

namespace comma
{
    std::pair<E, E> operator , (E lhs, E rhs) { return { lhs, rhs }; }
}

int main()
{
    C c;

    {
        using namespace comma; // operator , is valid here.

        std::cout << c[E::A, E::B] << std::endl;
        auto p = (E::A, E::B); // but also here :/ p = {E::A, E::B}
        static_cast<void>(p);
    }
    {
        std::cout << c[E::A, E::B] << std::endl; // result in c[E::B]
        auto p = (E::A, E::B); // p = E::B
        static_cast<void>(p);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bd8f33c44fb1e10)

as alternative, you may use regular method, `operator ()` method (which can take several parameter), use `std::pair`/`std::tuple` as argument (that would require extra enclosing `{}` at call site).

Comment: This is cool! Thanks for this. So, using namespaces, I could theoretically also use e.g. `std::pair<int, int> operator , (int lhs, int rhs) { return { lhs, rhs }; }` within that scope, without mucking up other uses of the comma operator, outside of that scope, right?

Comment: `operator,` must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type. so `int`/`int` would be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to overload operators for specific contexts only. You can still limit its use based on the types of the operator thou.

Answer (score 0):

When you overload an operator, you're specifying which types are valid to be used with this operator. So it would be a good idea to design it with the types defined within your class.

```
class YourClass
{
public:
class YourType{};
};

pair<YourClass::YourType, YourClass::YourType> operator , (YourClass::YourType p1, YourClass::YourType p2)
{
    return make_pair(p1, p2);
}
```

But if you need some form of generalization, you can use templates and template specialization.

Comment: Yes, this is also what the linked example in my question provides. I was just wondering whether it is also possible to do it safely for arguments of general types, but I guess this is not possible.