# In c++, is it possible to implement the function of accessing array element with grammar [i, j, ...] which just like the ndarray style in Numpy?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, multidimensional-array

In numpy, one can access the array as following

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3*2).reshape(3, 2)
b = a[0, 1]
```

In c++, is it possible to overload the operator [] to implement the similar function as `a[0, 1]`? Of course, the number of input arguments can vary.

Comment: Probably better to go with `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. [See the array subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

> To provide multidimensional array access semantics, e.g. to implement a 3D array access a[i][j][k] = x;, operator[] has to return a reference to a 2D plane, which has to have its own operator[] which returns a reference to a 1D row, which has to have operator[] which returns a reference to the element. To avoid this complexity, some libraries opt for overloading operator() instead, so that 3D access expressions have the Fortran-like syntax a(i, j, k) = x;

However a [related proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1161r2.html) has been made to eventually enable this.

Comment: *To avoid this complexity* means that it's **possible** but complicated. But that answer is for accessing the element as `a[i][j][k]`, **not** as `a[i, j, k]` as the OP wants. The comma operator can be overloaded easily to [access the element as `a[i, j, k]` easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136340/995714)

Comment: @phuclv this might be viable if you overloaded it on a strong type with an explicit constructor. I can imagine the confusion otherwise, when passing multiple numbers to an unrelated function.