# C++ Cholesky factorization

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I need to rewrite some MatLab code using C++.

Inside the Matlab code, we are calling the function `chol` to calculate an upper triangular matrix.

For the C++ part, I'm starting to look at Eigen. 
However, I struggle to get an equivalent of Matlab's `chol` function.

I tried to use the `LDLT` class of Eigen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main() {

  MatrixXd matA(2, 2);
  matA << 1, 2, 3, 4;

  MatrixXd matB(4, 4);
  matB << matA, matA/10, matA/10, matA;
  matB = matB*matB.transpose();

  Eigen::LDLT<MatrixXd> tmp(matB);
  MatrixXd U = tmp.matrixU();
  cout << U << endl;
}
```

but the result is different compared to the Matlab code:

```
matB = [  1   2 0.1 0.2
          3   4 0.3 0.4
        0.1 0.2   1   2
        0.3 0.4   3   4];
matB = matB*matB';
D = chol(matB);
```

Comment: That's because "`matB << matA, matA/10, matA/10, matA;`" does not do what you think it does. The only thing that happens here is `matB << MatA`, and everything else gets completely ignored. If you do not know how to do something in C++, just trying random syntax until it compiles is unlikely to produce the expected results. P.S. Same thing with "`matA << 1, 2, 3, 4;`", looks to me like [you could use a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no need to be offensive. Please provide more information. If I execute `cout << matB` it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Now try `cout << matA, matB` and see if you note any difference. That's my entire point.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik According to the very basic examples of Eigen it is perfectly fine syntax. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Comment: But according to people who know C++, [the comma operator should not be overloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator), so it's doing something that has so many pitfalls, that it's hard to avoid them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you want to say that Eigen is doing things wrong and you should avoid Eigen? However, this does not help me with my problem at all. You can think of the initialization done differently if you wish.

Comment: @user7431005 Eigen is perfectly fine in overloading `operator,`. The answer Sam is quoting actually says (plus the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator#comment93931744_5602136)) that if you don't know what you're doing, then you shouldn't overload `operator,`.

Comment: @user7431005: The problem here is in `(std::cout<<matA), matA/10, matA/10, matA` versus `std::cout << (matA, matA/10, matA/10, matA)`. Eigen can overload `operator<<` and `operator,` but it can't alter their precedence.

Comment: To those who are focusing on the operator overloading, Eigen did it fine. In fact, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/eQj2kX) is proof that the matrix OP thinks was computed matches the one later in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your code example and the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html), I get the same result when using LLT instead of LDLT ([online](https://godbolt.org/z/XS6s2q)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd matA(3,3);
  matA << 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3;
  cout << matA << "\n\n";
  Eigen::LDLT<MatrixXd> tmp(matA);
  cout << ((tmp.info() == Success) ? "succeeded" : "failed") << "\n\n";
  MatrixXd U = tmp.matrixL();
  cout << U << "\n\n";
  // Using LLT instead
  cout << MatrixXd(matA.llt().matrixL()) << "\n\n";
  cout << MatrixXd(matA.llt().matrixU()) << "\n\n";
}
```

Outputs:

> 1 0 1
>   0 2 0
>   1 0 3
>
> succeeded
>
> 1        0        0
>   0        1        0
>   0.333333        0        1
>
> 1       0       0
>   0 1.41421       0
>   1       0 1.41421
>
> 1       0       1
>   0 1.41421       0
>   0       0 1.41421

Answer (score 2):

According the documentation of [Eigen::LDTL](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LDLT.html) the 2nd template parameter `_UpLo` defaults to `Lower` but you omitted that parameter and want to calculate the upper triangular matrix.

So your class instantiation should look similar to this (don't know if the correct Eigen-define here is `Upper`):

```
Eigen::LDLT<MatrixXd, Upper> tmp(matB);
```

**Edit** 
@chtz is right - using `Upper`wont give you the result you expect because `LDLT` class is for robust cholesky decomposition with pivoting.
So in in Addition to the correct answer of @Avi you can also use the right class for standard cholesky decomposition:

```
Eigen::LLT<MatrixXd> tmp(matA);
cout <<  MatrixXd(tmp.matrixU()) << "\n\n";
```

Comment: The `_UpLo` parameter describes which half of the input matrix is considering. You can output either factor using `.matrixL()` or `.matrixU()` (these are just different views to the same data though). The correct answer is to use `LLT` instead of `LDLT` as @Avi pointed out.