# What is the purpose of (void) casts in the GCC standard library implementation?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, std-ranges

In the implementation of `std::ranges::transform` in GCC's stdlibc++, why does the `for` loop iterator increment have a `(void)` cast?

```cpp
for (; __first1 != __last1 && __first2 != __last2;
         ++__first1, (void)++__first2, ++__result)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is because in C++ it is [possible to overload the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator). The benefit of that still eludes me to this day, but that's not important right now. The important point is that it's possible.

The explicit `void` cast prevents unintended side effects from an unexpected invocation of an overloaded operator here, with unwanted results. Note how a single `void` cast effectively prevents the comma operator on both the left and the right side from getting invoked.

Comment: To be clear: both comma operators are applied, but they're the built-in comma operator. It's user-defined overloads that don't get applied. The `void` poisons them, because overloaded operators are functions, and you can't pass `void` as an argument to a function.