# What's the difference between start=i,end=j; and start=i; end=j;

Tags: c++, arrays, sliding-window

The question was "Max Continuous Series of 1s"

> You are given an array of 1s and 0s. And you are given an integer M, which signifies number of flips allowed.
>
> Find the position of zeros which when flipped will produce maximum continuous series of 1s.

I used sliding window approach to solve the answer, but there is something I noticed that if I write `start=i;end=j;` its wrong, but `start=i,end=j;` is right.

What's the difference between the execution of them?

```cpp
vector<int> Solution::maxone(vector<int> &A, int B) {
    int n=A.size();
    int start=0,end=0,count=0,i,j;
    
    for(i=0,j=0;j<n;){
        if(B>=0 && !A[j++])
       
        B--;
        
        if(B<0 && !A[i++])
        
        B++;
        
        if(end-start<j-i)
        start=i,end=j;    // Here I get wrong ans if I write start=i;end=j;
    }
    
    vector<int> v;
    while(start<end)
    v.push_back(start++);
    
    return v;
    
}
```

Comment: Because you don't use brackets `{ }` in the `if`. So `start=i,end=j;` is a single line and part of the `if` but `start=i;end=j;` is 2 lines and only the first one belongs to the `if`.

Comment: @mocha_nirvana No, "_we_" never do. Why wouldn't you use brackets?

Comment: Personally, I _always_ use brackets - even for "one liners".

Comment: Let me correct that for you: *Ok so to execute such a line after `if` and we* **always** *use brackets we* **never** *use a comma.*

Comment: the comma operator is a weird beast, often uses are accidentally, and often wrong. It has some use-cases, but this isnt one. In some sense `start=i,end=j;` is only correct by luck.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks! I am new and still learning. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: "to execute such a line after if and not use brackets we use a comma" - Would a great way to leave a landmine that could trip up future developers (including yourself) and then introduce subtle bugs. I would never let this pass code review and get checked in to any real codebase.

Comment: Generalization: Don't surprise people. Surprised people make bugs.

Comment: please dont change the question after you got answers to ask for something else. The question you now put in the title already has been asked I believe and the answers you got adress a slightly different question

Comment: for more on comma operator see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+comma+operator)

Answer (score 7):

In case of `start=i;end=j;` you get

```cpp
if(end-start<j-i)
  start=i;
end = j;
```

because `;` make `end=j;` an another statement

`start=i,end=j;` is a one statement, because comma is a [Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Solution: use `if() {}`

Answer (score 2):

`start = i, end = j;` is a single statement. `start = i; end = j;` is two statements. An `if` controls the next statement. So:

```
if (false)
    start = i, end = j;
```

doesn’t modify `start` or `end`.

```
if (false)
    start = i; end = j;
```

modifies `end` because `end = j` is the **second** statement after the `if`, so the `if` does not affect it.

```
if (false) {
    start = i; end = j;
}
```

doesn’t modify `start` or `end` because both assignments are inside the **compound statement** delimited by the curly braces. The compound statement is the single statement that the `if` controls.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the problem is simple `if` you are not using curly brackets `{}` due without curly brackets so only one statement (not line) is considered under `if` as `true statement` so as soon as you put `;` it will complete the one statement.

```
if()
    <true statement>;

if(){
   <true statement>;
   <true statement>;
}
```

Secondly, if you format your code properly then you will easily able to get the bug.

Finally, when you keep `,` instead of `;` then it will be considered as single statement

Comment: Actually, an `if` always controls exactly one statement. When you write `if () { … }` the curly braces designate a compound statement, which is a single statement that encloses zero or more statements.