# How boost format works in terms of c++?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

I was looking at boost::format documents and just the first example made me wondering:

```
cout << boost::format("writing %1%,  x=%2% : %3%-th try") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50;
```

What does it mean in terms of c++? I can understand call to boost::format itself, there's nothing strange there, but what's the meaning of the rest?

```
% "toto" % 40.23 % 50
```

Am I missing some special meaning '%' has in c++? What does this mean in terms of the language? I had a look into headers, but they're not particularly readable to be honest)

Comment: just like how `std::cout` overloads `<<` to do its work, `boost::format` does the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%`, like many operators in C++, can be overloaded for arbitrary types. If we have the expression `a % b` where `a` is of type `A` and `b` is of type `B`, then C++ will look for functions compatible with the following signatures.

```
R operator%(const A& a, const B& b);
R A::operator%(const B& b) const;
```

So, presumably, `boost::format` returns some custom class, on which `operator%` is defined. The `operator%` defined there takes this custom class and a string and produces a new instance of this custom class. Finally, when we `std::cout << ...` the custom class, Boost provides an overload for *that* as well which prints out the string representation.

If we remove all of the operators and pretend everything is ordinary method calls, effectively this

```
cout << boost::format("writing %1%,  x=%2% : %3%-th try") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50;
```

becomes

```
pipe(std::cout, percent(percent(percent(boost::format(...), "toto"), 40.23), 50));
```

And overload resolution on the names `pipe` and `percent` takes care of the rest.

Comment: oooooooooooooh! simple. Although I have to mention that this is the last operator I could thought about in that way. I've kind of failed into the trap of forgetting that this is just another operator. Something you never really do in real life. 
I'll leave it here just for the additional reading -- Which Operators Cannot Be Overloaded https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#overloadable-opers

Comment: @Roman you'll be surprised to see the useless comma operator due to the low precedence can be [overloaded in clerver ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602112/995714). And C++20 made comma operator deprecated inside `[]` to prepare for more useful overloads in the future