# Repeated Class Instantiation without using Identifier

Tags: c++, unique, anonymous

I want to repeatedly instantiate a class, within module scope, without providing a unique name. Something like this.

```
MyClass name##__LINE__(); // doesn't work because __LINE__ won't stringify
MyClass name##__LINE__(); // duplicate identifier error - two name__LINE__ variables
```

Is there some way to do this, either creating a unique name or using some anonymous context, such as an initializer or struct?

Comment: Is `MyClass arr[N]` an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ macro/template blackmagic to generate unique name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419720/3959454)

```
#define CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y) x##y
#define CONCATENATE(x, y) CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y)
#define MAKE_UNIQUE(x) CONCATENATE(x, __LINE__)

MyClass MAKE_UNIQUE(name);
MyClass MAKE_UNIQUE(name);
...
```

Or just make an array:

```
MyClass arr[N];
```

**Why these macros work**
C11 standard, `6.10.3.1 Argument substitution`:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>   argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
>   by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other
>   preprocessing tokens are available.

Corresponding paragraph in C++ standard (`16.3.1 Argument substitution`) is exact copy of C standard's.

Comment: Can anyone verify that this solution is standards conforming? Can I expect that it will work with all conforming implementations?

Comment: Discovered that `__LINE__` isn't unique for #include files. I changed to `__COUNTER__` which is supported by Visual Studio and gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double nest the concatenation operator

```
struct A{};

#define JOIN(X, Y) JOIN_DETAIL(X, Y)
#define JOIN_DETAIL(X, Y) JOIN_DETAIL2(X, Y)
#define JOIN_DETAIL2(X, Y) X##Y

int main() {
    A JOIN(a, __LINE__);
    A JOIN(a, __LINE__);
}
```